# Am I required to replace the aluminum wire with copper when selling my home?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am selling a home built in 1970 that has some copper wiring in fuse box. Is it necessary to replace copper wiring in a breaker box to sell my home built in the 70s?

Comment: Title says "replace aluminum" and body says "replace copper". Not sure what you're asking. But in any case, pictures would help.

Comment: Probably not required to if it was done in code at the time(70s).  Buyers might be turned off because of the aluminum wires and choose to not buy.  The problem with aluminum is it is softer and the connections get loose over time and heat up.  Big aluminum wires do not have this problem as much as the smaller wires.

Comment: If it's big wires, copper or aluminum are both fine.

Comment: If I see a **fuse box**, I'm discounting any purchase offer by the price of a new **breaker panel**, at least. I want no part of actual fuses or the archaic circuit choices made in the era when they were common. 6 circuits for the whole house - whee! Aluminum branch circuit wiring (15/20A) would be an additional discount, but you're unlikely to make back the cost of addressing either issue, rather than simply disclosing them and expecting the buyer to lower their offer to suit.

Comment: Hard to know what the OP's situation is so I'm just going to throw some things out for consderation. My circa 1970 GE panel was rated for copper or aluminum. All of the original wiring was aluminum, except for the cable to the a/c condensing unit. It was solid copper #8.  In the panel I copper pigtailed all the neutrals for the 120 V circuits because the screws on the neutral bus would not make good contact with the #12 Al neutrals. So I have a bunch of "copper wiring in a breaker box". There would be no reason to remove or replace the copper in the panel so I would not do such a thing.

Comment: Only thing I could get from the question is that the OP wonders if it was improper to have a mix of aluminum and copper in the breaker box. Answer is NO, nothing improper.

Comment: It is actually a good question.    There are a lot of home owners that wonder about this and I hear weird things all the time from people.    ~10 years ago or so there was an outcry to not insure aluminum... probably the electrician's union lobbyist (I joke but could be true).   Anyway most people don't follow the latest aluminum trends like harper and ecnerwal  - who I am positive have phone alerts for code changes :)

Comment: @DMoore it *could be* a good question. It's not, though. It conflicts with itself (fuse or breaker? remove aluminum or remove copper?  it needs pictures, and it needs adequate [edit]ing effort (by the OP to actually sort out what they are asking) to be self consistent and ask a clear question.

Comment: The OP needs to tell us where in the world they are. Code could say one thing or the direct opposite - without a location we have no clue what it might be.

Answer (score 3):

Aluminum is only scary due to some blunders in the 1960s-1970s with small 15-20 amp branch circuits, owing to a hasty attempt to use aluminum wire because of a copper shortage. However, with 60 years of experience, we now know what to do.

- Make sure the terminals they are attached to are properly rated for aluminum.  Alumiconn style lug connectors (whose lug body is made of aluminum much like the neutral bar on the panel)... or the COPALUM power-crimp splices, or devices specifically rated for aluminum wire, e.g. the AL-CU rating on things larger than 20A, or the CO-ALR rating on 15-20A devices.
- The screw torque on the terminal screws is correct and set by a tool that actually measures that, because [no one has a calibrated arm](https://www.ecmweb.com/construction/article/20890860/do-you-have-a-calibrated-arm).

These rules apply to copper as well - the science around screw torque was actually discovered relating to copper (they weren't even thinking of aluminum) but we have no reason to think aluminum would sidestep the problem.  Indeed, it explains a lot about what went wrong in the 70s, which is the origin of the aluminum fears now driving your question.  The devices were simply made-for-copper and not adequately tested. Nobody was using a torque screwdriver on small stuff back then.

Answer (score 3):

On a more general note, but directly answering the question **Am I required to replace the aluminum wire with copper when selling my home?**:

As I understand it in the United States there are very few, *if any*, things you are required to fix, replace, etc. when you sell a home. The key is **disclosure**. If you have:

- Aluminum branch wiring
- Radon
- Asbestos
- Work not properly done to code (electrical, plumbing, general building code, etc.)
- Flooding in the basement
- Leaks in the roof
- Broken major appliances or HVAC
- Breaker panel with known problem (e.g., Federal Pacific)

or really almost any other problem, the key is to disclose it to the potential buyer. If they know about a problem then it may affect the price they are willing to pay, but *you are not required to fix the problem*. A buyer could write up a contract that says:

- We'll pay the price you asked, as is
- We'll pay less than you asked, as is
- We'll pay more than you asked, as is (happens a lot in a tight real estate market)
- We'll pay 'x' (list, more or less, whatever) if you fix 'y' but if you don't then we'll only pay 'x'-'z'.

Now some jurisdictions may require an *occupancy permit* for the new owner to move in. If that's the case then *some* problems will need to be resolved - either by the seller or the buyer. But many other problems are things of concern but not *required* to be fixed by anyone.

If aluminum wiring was installed according to code *at the time* then replacing it may be wise but is very unlikely to be *required*.

On the other hand, if you do not disclose a known problem and the sale is completed and *then* the buyer finds out about the problem, they could choose to sue you for damages. One reason for the common, but not required and definitely not universal, practice of a home inspector hired by the buyer is to find problems, whether the seller knows about them or not, before buying a property. But even a home inspector won't find everything - one that concentrates on plumbing or structural items may not even know where/how to look for aluminum wiring.

Comment: In my jurisdiction an occupancy permit is required before a house is sold, meaning that it's the seller's responsibility to fix. In rare cases the seller might go to the buyer and somehow convince them to chip in, but the seller is the one legally responsible. However, what an occupancy permit covers varies greatly by area. Ours covers obvious safety hazards (broken floors, broken stairs, broken windows, working fire alarms, etc.) and basic external stuff (garbage/refuse on the property, building coverings in working order).

Answer (score 2):

There are localities that require you to pigtail aluminum wiring as Harper has suggested.

There are even a few communities that have banned the sale of houses with aluminum wiring on branch circuits (15/20A).   I am not sure I have heard of this recently as with the updates in products and code, there is nothing wrong with aluminum when done right.    But for sure this was a thing 10 years ago and there might be some localities left doing this.

So you need to call your city hall and just ask them.   There is no national code requirement that affects you selling your house.